# Sphero-Android SDK Locator documentation

Tags: android, sphero-api

Hi I was reading the sphero docs for the locator app and about half way down in the 'Making the mos of the locator' Section.  The bullet parts tell you to reference different numbers in order to achieve each bullet.  I am not seeing where these numbers are being referenced to.  If anyone knows or can explain that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That section of the doc is a text flowchart.  I'll reformatted to make it a little more clear in the next version of the SDK.  Below is the change.

### Want to know Position?

- Use Roll Commands to move Sphero to a locator position - See  "The Full Setup" in the doc

  - https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/master/samples/Locator#the-full-setup
- Use the locator data to 'know' where Sphero is - See "The Default Setup" in the doc

  - https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/master/samples/Locator#the-default-setup

### Want to know distance travelled?

- Find Odometer distance - See "Distance Travelled"

  - https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/master/samples/Locator#distance-traveled
- Distance 'as a crow flies' - See "Default Setup"

  - https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/master/samples/Locator#the-default-setup